# How to run PHP script on server without needing a web browser

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, browser, graph, server

I use php for my Facebook bots that use graph API. The scripts contain get and post requests etc, but in order to run the script, I have to visit the URL in a browser, for example I use xammp for local host, so i have to constantly have 127.0.0.1 open in my browser. When I go to the web page, the script runs once. I want the script to be running every x seconds, and what i do right now is I have a header refresh of x seconds. This means the browser reloads the page, and the script runs again every x seconds.

What i want is for my server to do this on its own, without needing a client to visit the webpage. Is there some sort of php technique i should be using?

As a side note, when i use webhooks in php with graph API, i do not need to have a browser window open. It all runs just using the server.

Comment: You have 2 options.If you would like to use AWS or already are, you can use the SQS service with a cron.yaml file in your source directory. Another option is to install cron. I am not sure if you can do that on a windows machine.

Comment: you should tag your question with Heroku if your using it as its quite different to most other servers

Answer (score 0):

Use a Cron Job, with PHP command line to execute your script.

Comment: Is there a way to run cross jobs  heroku or do I need a cpanel thing whatever they're called

Comment: @EthanSK Heroku  has a Scheduler, if i understood the comment

Comment: Looks like it have a scheduler: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler also for a more exact execution:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes

Comment: Hmm. Cron jobs are not working. I forgot to mention that I have to be logged into facebook, which uses cache to keep me logged in. Could this be stopping cronjobs from working?

Answer (score -1):

If you are planning to run the script for every x seconds (x small ) then the best choice if to run the script one time, using an infinite loop, and  `sleep  ()` to pause the script for x second before continuing excution.

For example `bot.php` must look like this

```
#!/usr/sbin/php
<?php
function run_bot (){
    ...
 }

 while  ( 1 ){
      run_bot ();
      sleep(x);
 }
```

And after that in shell type this:

```
 chmod +x bot.php

 nohup ./bot.php &
```